# Cant get ALSA to recognize sound device | Lenovo G560

Tags: 12.04, sound, kernel, lenovo, alsa

I am a returning Ubuntu user after a pause of a few years, so I have forgotten quite a bit.

My problem is that ALSA will not list my soundcard at all.. It cant find it.
aplay command returns with: `aplay: device_list:221: no soundcard found...`

My hardware does recognize it tho:

```
:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38af
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at 9b100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel


01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at 93000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel**
```

I've tried several things. 
This: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Updated kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150215/my-sound-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04

After that update, my system broke, so updated kernel to 3.5.0-45-generic

I guess you want the specs as well: http://www.lapspecs.com/detail/lenovo+g560
|| It's the i5 430M'

Every time I boot up i get an error report on oss4-dkms:

> DKMS make.log for oss4-4.2-build2005 for kernel 3.5.0-45-generic
>   (i686)
>
> cp: cannot
>   stat`/lib/modules/3.5.0-45-generic/source/include/linux/limits.h': No
>   such file or directory

I am out of ideas on how to fix this. 
Help is appreciated!

Comment: I couldn't post another link, but here is the alsa-info-script link: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=cce86dbbeccdcf0f207840427e7012d97312d8ab

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved! 
I did some digging, and found a script to update the ALSA system. 
http://www.stchman.com/alsa_update.html

After downloading the script you need to give it execute permission, for example

```
chmod u+x alsa_setup.sh

#!/bin/sh

# This script will recompile the ALSA drivers for Ubuntu
# This procedure was gotten from
# https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto
#
# Authored by Bob Nelson  admin@stchman.com
#
# This script updated 9/6/2007


script_name="alsa_setup.sh"

# Script must run as root 
if [ $USER != "root" ]; then
        echo "You need to run this script as root."
        echo "Use 'sudo ./$script_name' then enter your password when prompted."
        exit 1
fi

# Install the required tools
apt-get -y install build-essential ncurses-dev gettext

# Install your kernel headers
apt-get -y install linux-headers-`uname -r`

# Change to users home folder
cd ~

# Get the files from www.stchman.com
wget http://www.stchman.com/tools/alsa/alsa-driver-1.0.16.tar.bz2
wget http://www.stchman.com/tools/alsa/alsa-lib-1.0.16.tar.bz2
wget http://www.stchman.com/tools/alsa/alsa-utils-1.0.16.tar.bz2

# make a new folder
mkdir -p /usr/src/alsa

# Change to that folder
cd /usr/src/alsa

# Copy the downloaded files to the newly made folder
cp ~/alsa* .

# Unpack the tar archive files
tar xjf alsa-driver*
tar xjf alsa-lib*
tar xjf alsa-utils*

#Compile and install alsa-driver
cd alsa-driver*
./configure --with-cards=hda-intel --with-kernel=/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)
make
make install

# Compile and install alsa-lib
cd ../alsa-lib*
./configure
make
make install

# Compile and install alsa-utils
cd ../alsa-utils*
./configure
make
make install

# Remove the archives as they are no longer needed
rm -f ~/alsa-driver*
rm -f ~/alsa-lib*
rm -f ~/alsa-utils*

# Add the following line to the file, replacing '3stack' with your model
echo -e '\n' >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=3stack" >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base

# Reboot the computer
reboot
```

I still get the oss4 error. But the sound works!

Answer (score 0):

Installing OSS4 disables the kernel's built-in sound drivers.
(And in your case, the bugs in OSS disable the OSS drivers.)

Uninstall OSS4.

Comment: I did.. Kept having problems. I did some digging last night after posting the problem, and found this brilliant update script for ALSA: http://www.stchman.com/alsa_update.html 

My sound works now, just not trough Flash plug-ins.
But for some reason i still get that oss4 error, even though i was thorough with purging all oss4 packages. 

But thanks for the help. It's appreciated